# Passing arguments to iOS tests with xcodebuild

Tags: xcodebuild

I'd like to pass command line arguments to my iOS tests through the command line (xcodebuild). I'm looking for the equivalent of this setting on XCode:

[image: Arguments]

Simply passing the argument to xcodebuild doesn't work, e.g.:

```
xcodebuild -verbose test -workspace theworkspace.xcworkspace -scheme 'thescheme' -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 7' --argument=value
```

This question is similar to [xcodebuild pass arguments to application on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40235209/xcodebuild-pass-arguments-to-application-on-ios) but the solution to that question is not satisfactory.

Comment: Where you able to figure this out? I am trying to do the same to pass some testing data to my unit tests.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23284829/accessing-user-defined-variables-passed-in-from-xcodebuild-command-line

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? It would help us all out if you shared it.

Comment: This answer works fine (By @Ivano.Bilenchi in above comment). No manual steps needed. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23284829/accessing-user-defined-variables-passed-in-from-xcodebuild-command-line

Answer (score 10):

It's about passing environment variables rather of command line arguments, but it looks like there's a chance it's supported in xcodebuild in Xcode 13. From [release notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-13-release-notes#:%7E:text=any%20variable%20with-,TEST_RUNNER_,-to%20pass%20that):

> xcodebuild now supports passing certain environment variables to test runner processes. In the environment where xcodebuild is invoked, prefix any variable with TEST_RUNNER_ to pass that variable (with the prefix stripped) to XCTest test runner processes. For example, running env TEST_RUNNER_Foo=Bar xcodebuild test ... causes the environment variable Foo=Bar to be set in the test runner’s environment. (74104870)

Answer (score 4):

You can also try creating a [preprocessor macros](http://blog.manbolo.com/2013/05/17/passing-user-variable-to-xcodebuild) in the build settings.
And then pass a value like this (let's assume it's named DARK_MODE):

```
xcodebuild -project \
   -scheme  \
   -testPlan  \
   -destination \
   -derivedDataPath \
   DARK_MODE=NO \
   test
```

And here's how it can be utilized in tests:

```
override func setUp() {
    super.setUp()
    if ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment["DARK_MODE"] == "YES" {
        SystemSettings.changeUIStyle(to: .dark)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I didn't manage to find "easy" solution. So instead I split testing in 3 steps:
 1. Run `xcodebuild build-for-testing`. It will generate `xctestrun` file in derived data, which contains list of launch arguments
 2. Add your desire launch arguments here
 3. run `xcodebuild test-without-building -xctestrun <%path_to_file_here%>`

I wrote script for it. It still need some improvements, so in close time I will share its final form.

**Edit:** Never had time to update script. So here ugly versions, that suit our needs.
https://gist.github.com/ManWithBear/57cbabc8dcd0193d156c376d2d23ff02

Comment: Very useful script! Instead of the Swift Plistbuddy would probably be better, but it does work!

Comment: Yeah, I gave a try to plistbuddy, but failed to use it properly, so write swift script was way faster. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Quite like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47762549

Answer (score 2):

To add to @ManWithBear's answer, I ended up doing this in a script:

```
#Remove previous command line arguments
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Delete DetoxTestRunner:CommandLineArguments" "$TESTRUN" || true
#Add an empty array
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Add DetoxTestRunner:CommandLineArguments array" "$TESTRUN"

#Add script arguments as launch arguments of the test runner app
for i in $*; do
  /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Add DetoxTestRunner:CommandLineArguments: string '$i'" "$TESTRUN"
done
```

In the code above, I add all arguments passed to a script as launch argument to the tester app. `DetoxTestRunner` is the name if the test scheme/target.